# Refactoring Javascript Function inside a Function

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, refactoring

I would like some tips on refactoring the following code, to be honest, it's not really complex but I'm still learning best practices and conventions.

HTML:

```
<div class="joke-container">
  <div class="joke-text">
    "This is a boring Static Joke"
  </div>
  <div class="joke-control">
    <button type="button" value="Random">Random</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const jokes = [
  '"This is a very funny Joke"',
  '"This is another super crazy Joke"',
  '"OMFG this is so random"'
];

const randomJokeButton = document.querySelector(
  "button[type=button][value=Random]"
);

function randomJoke(jokes) {
  return (joke = jokes[Math.floor(Math.random() * jokes.length)]);
}

function printJoke(joke) {
  let jokeText = document.querySelector(".joke-text");
  return (jokeText.textContent = joke);
}

randomJokeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  printJoke(randomJoke(jokes));
});
```

SCSS:

```
@mixin center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.joke-container {
  @include center;
  background: white;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 900px;
}

.joke-text {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body {
  background: papayawhip;
}

button {
  background: papayawhip;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

So the part I'm not really sure about is:

```
randomJokeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  printJoke(randomJoke(jokes));
});
```

Basically, the way I call the function inside another function with an argument doesn't really make me happy, maybe it's the correct way I don't really know, maybe I should place it inside a variable?.

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ricardoNava/pen/mMLRxb) for the project.

Comment: Remove `(joke = ` inside `randomJoke`, and possibly the `return` inside `printJoke`, everything else is completely fine. Especially the arrow function event handler, there's nothing to worry about here.

Comment: @Bergi Can you explain why I don't need a `return` on `printJoke`?

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with it, but it doesn't seem necessary. Can you explain why you do need the `return` value?

Comment: @Bergi Not really, I just thought functions needed a return. :)